# Validation Failed exception Liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I am newbie in using liquibase for database management. I am getting the following error while doing mvn install. I am not able to know where exactly i went wrong. Could someone please help me with the solution

```
 Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
         1 changes have validation failures
              'sql' is required, db/changelog/changes/v0001.sql::raw::includeAll
```

**db.changelog-master.yaml**

```
databaseChangeLog:
    - includeAll:
        path: db/changelog/changes/
```

[liquibase folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zw9L.png)

Comment: What's the content of `v0001.sql`? There must be a changeset in there that causes the validation failed exception message "'sql' is required".

Answer (score 6):

In liquibase whenever a migration is run it creates a hash value for each of the change log written in migration file. When the application is run for the first time entry is created for each change log with its hash values in the **DatabaseChangelog** Table.`If a change is made to the existing change log which has been run once the hash value changes and a validation error is generated.`
To fix this issue

> you can revert the changes made to the change log after it was run for
>   the first time and create a new change log to accommodate the change

OR

> delete the entries in the DatabaseChangeLog table for the particular
>   change log giving error along with the change associated with the
>   change log and rerun your migration.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add query altogether. Just added the changeset!

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned appears if you define changeset with empty SQL tag like this:

```
<changeSet id="test_users" author="test" dbms="h2">
    <sql>

    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

To fix it just remove this incomplete changeset or finish it by adding some SQL script you originally intended.